# Windows 10 update

Tags: windows, iis, windows-update

After install the big windows 10 update in December of 2017 by IIS stop to work and refuse to start. They are other services also that stopped (WAS) and also refuse to start. some one can help me please about how to resolve these issues?

Comment: If you're very sure that the culprit is Windows 10 latest installed update, then you can simply uninstall the update from "Control Panel -> Programs & Features -> View Installed Updates -> Select the culprit update -> Uninstall".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes I am sure, I installed the update and when I begin to use the computer the IIS was down. Yes I can uninstall the update, but that is not for me a  real solution. I supposed that Microsoft does not make a two hours update because its considered it interesting. Thanks any way.

Answer (score 2):

After two days I found the solution:

- Go to Turn Windows features on or off applet 
  [image]
- Un-check Windows Process Activation Service
- Un-Check Internet Information Service (maybe it is
  good write down the actual configuration)
- Restart the computer
- Check    Windows Process Activation service Check Internet
  Information Service    (you can use the previous write down
  configuration to set your    previous settings)
- Restart the computer.

Now the two services should be running. Enjoy!

Comment: Also, if anything happens after Windows updates, you can always roll back it at any time. https://www.howtogeek.com/206271/how-to-roll-back-or-uninstall-a-problematic-windows-update/